# jquery make an animated menu that animates the main body also

Tags: jquery

im trying to learn some jquery so i wanted to make a responsive menu.
The menu is currently "hidden" (-250px left from body) and i have an image, so i want when i click the image the #menu div get animated 250px from left ( so it will get shown at main page) and the main body get animated also 250px left (something like #menu push the body 250px). Here is the code i made but currenlty doesnt work and i get no errors at console-log.

```
#menu {
position:relative;
float:left;
left:-250px;
}


<img id="menu-icon" src="images/menu_icon.png"/>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Login/Register</li>
<li>About</li>
<li>Contact</li>
<li>Random</li>
</ul>
</div>


$('#menu-icon').click(function(){
    $('#menu').animate({
    left : "250px" }, 5000, function() {
        $(document).animate({
    left: "250px" 
    });
 });
});
```

Can someone enlight me on what i do wrong ?
I also tried do that with:

```
$('menu').css("left","250px");
```

but also nothing happened.

Comment: Change `$(document)` to `$(document.body)`

Comment: Change `$('menu').css("left","250px");` to `$('#menu').css("left","250px");`

Comment: done but nothing happened. Its not only the body, but also the menu doesnt get animated.

Comment: Working fine on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope, you are having the code at the end of closing body, if not put your code inside ready handler. And next thing you want to animate to body itself too. So, use 'body' not document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#menu-icon').click(function(){
    $('#menu').animate({
    left : "250px" }, 5000, function() {
        $('body').animate({
    left: "250px" 
    });
 });
});
});
```

And if you want to animate each time by adding 250px then use "+=250px"

Comment: I actually include the script in the head
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script> shouldnt i ?

Comment: Ok now it work fine ! altough im kinda lost.I have to use ALWAYS $(document).ready handler ?

Comment: If you insert your script before the end of closing body then you don't need and if you insert your code in head then use ready..

Comment: Or the menu is getting animated, but not the body.I have a header and it stays in the same position.

Comment: because you haven't applied css for body position:relative; so better would be using margin-left instead of left...and if you use margin-left then you don't need to apply body{position:relative;}

Comment: Im so dumb, forgot that :D Now it works fine. Thanks for the explanations also.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a better solution :

CSS :

```
body {
    position : relative;
}
```

JS :

```
$('#menu-icon').click(function(){
    $('body').animate({
        marginLeft : '250px' 
    }, 500);
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/7tgkt7b9/